# Is it possible to find the Eigenvalues of a square matrix by reducing it into echelon form then finding what values lead to a 0 in the diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I was taught that the determinant of a triangular matrix is just the product of all the entries in its diagonal. Yet when I reduce the matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 3\\
    0 & 3 & 0\\
    4 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
to:
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 3\\
    0 & 3 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & -5
\end{bmatrix}
The Eigenvalues I find with the equation $\det(A- \lambda I) = 0$ are 2, 3, and -5. The correct values are 3, 5, and -2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Clearly you can't in general reduce a matrix to echelon form without changing the eigenvalues, as you can make a matrix with eigenvalues different from $1$ by "unreducing" the identity matrix.

Comment: Thanks! I think that clears it up.